# How to get variable and pass value to API using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I need to pass these values ​​to an API using JSON.stringify and I need to get the variables in the object.
The object that the API receives needs to look exactly like this:

```
{
  "sessionInformation": "{\"emailAddress\" : \"the value\",\"firstName\" : \"the name\", \"question\" : \"the text\"}"
}
```

I'm trying this, but I'm not sure exactly how to concatenate the variables in that context

```
const email = some.value,
const name = some.value,
const text = some.value,

const raw = JSON.stringify({
  sessionInformation:
     '{"emailAddress" : email,"firstName" : name, "question" : text}',
});
```

How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stringify internal object as well

```js
const email = "Email value";
const name = "Name value";
const text = "Text value";

const raw = JSON.stringify({
  sessionInformation: JSON.stringify({
    emailAddress: email,
    firstName: name,
    question: text
  }),
});

console.log(raw)
```